# Apache is not running on CentOS 7 Server

Tags: linux, apache, centos, bitrix

I'm running a Bitrix server over a CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 machine and I can't manage to get Apache work properly. I've tried restarting the Apache service but it didn't work.

I've checked the system logs via Webadmin and it shows the following:

> [Mon Mar 05 03:33:12.118466 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1351]
>   AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.0.26 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
>   configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Mon Mar 05 03:33:12.118482 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1351] AH00094:
>   Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
>
> [Mon Mar 05 11:19:46.641040 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1351]
>   AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
>
> [Mon Mar 05 11:20:15.021546 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 1360] AH01232:
>   suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
>
> [Mon Mar 05 11:20:15.107376 2018] [so:warn] [pid 1360] AH01574: module
>   socache_shmcb_module is already loaded, skipping
>
> [Mon Mar 05 11:20:17.068083 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1360]
>   AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.0.26 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
>   configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Mon Mar 05 11:20:17.068138 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1360] AH00094:
>   Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-scale.conf -D
>   FOREGROUND'
>
> [Mon Mar 05 11:36:43.537842 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1360]
>   AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
>
> [Mon Mar 05 11:37:13.314311 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 1351] AH01232:
>   suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
>
> [Mon Mar 05 11:37:13.351957 2018] [so:warn] [pid 1351] AH01574: module
>   socache_shmcb_module is already loaded, skipping
>
> [Mon Mar 05 11:37:15.361335 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1351]
>   AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.0.26 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
>   configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Mon Mar 05 11:37:15.361360 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1351] AH00094:
>   Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-scale.conf -D
>   FOREGROUND'
>
> [Mon Mar 05 11:49:01.192086 2018] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 1351]
>   AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising
>   the MaxRequestWorkers setting
>
> [Mon Mar 05 12:01:13.778293 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1351]
>   AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
>
> [Mon Mar 05 12:01:43.297586 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 1383] AH01232:
>   suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
>
> [Mon Mar 05 12:01:43.371237 2018] [so:warn] [pid 1383] AH01574: module
>   socache_shmcb_module is already loaded, skipping
>
> [Mon Mar 05 12:01:44.932973 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1383]
>   AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.0.26 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
>   configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Mon Mar 05 12:01:44.933001 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1383] AH00094:
>   Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-scale.conf -D
>   FOREGROUND'

I don't have any clue on what the problem might be. Apache used to work fine until we installed a Bitrix update on the server.

Any sort of help or comment about this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `[Mon Mar 05 11:49:01.192086 2018] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 1351] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting`

Answer (score 0):

Did you increase the `MaxRequestWorkers` setting as suggested in the logs?

Find the corresponding file:

```
grep -Ril MaxRequestWorkers /etc/httpd/
```

On CentOS usually it is `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. Open the file, increase the value of `MaxRequestWorkers` and restart the web server for the changes to take effect:

```
systemctl restart httpd
```